# Android - sqlite exceptions

Tags: android, sqlite

In an Android application I've developed I see SQLITE exceptions from time to time.

Most of the time (I would say ~98%) everything works fine, but I still get 40-50 SQLITE related exceptions a day.

This question is a bit theoretical as I'm trying to understand what can cause these errors, as I've tried a lot of fixes.

The 3 common errors I get are:

> database is locked
>
> database disk image is malformed (code 11)
>
> unable to open database file

This is the flow of the app:
The app is installed with a pre-populated database, which is copied from the assets folder.
I'm using a singleton which extends SQLiteOpenHelper.

I access the database from a few threads – only one of them might write to the DB.

**What can cause such exceptions? Is there a way to simulate them?** because I've tried without success.

I would gladly provide any other information that might help.

This is the method I use to open the database:

```
public SQLiteDatabase openDataBase() throws SQLException{

    String myPath = myContext.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath().replace("files", "databases")+File.separator + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    return myDataBase;
}
```

Comment: Are you closing the database properly before attempting to open it again? Since it works 98% of the time, I would say that you may have forgotten to close it in just 1 activity.

Comment: That was my inital thought. But when I've tried to reproduce these exceptions, I just didn't close the connection, and still didn't get any exception.

Comment: If the database is locked it could be that it is still processing a query while you attempt to do another one. Possibly do an anti lock on the transactions or you could attempt doing the queries in an Async method

Comment: My users are facing the same problem. Like said earlier in the question only 2% is facing the problem. Also, My user faces the database locked exception and App crash only when the first time database is accessed by the application.